# How to get the selected row ids sorted according to index in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using

```
getGridParam('selarrrow');
```

to get the rows that are selected,where the method returns me the selected row ids according to their selection,but I want the ids according to their index.Do I have to write a method to sort the ids or is there a inbuilt method which returns me the selected row ids in order of their indexes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the index of the row in the grid then you have to resort the array or id returned by `$("#gridId").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow")`. You can use [sort()](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method of `Array` with your custom sort function. You can just use the fact that ids are the ids of `<tr>` elements. So the DOM elements of `<tr>` has native implemented [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) property which you can get by `$("#"+rowid)[0].rowIndex`.

In the simplified form the code could be about the following

```js
var selRowIds = $("#gridId").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");

selRowIds.sort(function (id1, id2) {
    // one can use document.getElementById alternatively
    return $("#" + id1)[0].rowIndex - $("#" + id2)[0].rowIndex;
});
```

or you can use [namedItem](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) method instead

```js
var $grid = $("#gridId"),
    selRowIds = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"),
    rows = $grid[0].rows;

selRowIds.sort(function (id1, id2) {
    return rows.namedItem(id1).rowIndex - rows.namedItem(id2).rowIndex;
});
```

Probably you should include more verification in the code to be sure that the item with id will be found and it has the `rowIndex` property.

Comment: :Thank you,its working.I used getInd(rowId) for getting the index of the row.

Comment: @pavi: You are welcome! [getInd](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L3322-3331) does the same internally. So you can use API which are more comfortable for you.